# How to deal with zero padding using multiframe in the animate package?

Tags: external-files, animate

In the `animate` package, using `\multiframe`, how to deal with zero padding?
For example if I have 101 pictures from `pic0000.jpg` to `pic0100.jpg` and I want to do something like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[controls]{6}
\multiframe{101}{i=0+1}{
  The pic \i
  \includegraphics[height=.45\textheight]{pic\i}
 }
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

but with the variable I varying from 0000 to 0100.

Comment: `animate` has an internal macro for zero-padding you could use. See my answer below.

Comment: Tricky but that look the more straightforward.

Comment: It's versatile, as you can specify any number of digits as the template string without modifying/extending the macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, `animate` defines the macro `\@anim@pad{<template>}{<number>}` for zero-padding numbers according to a template which is a string of arbitrary digits of the desired width.

In the example below `\i` is formatted (zero-padded) to four digits width (0000...0100):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\let\zeropad\@anim@pad
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[controls]{6}
\multiframe{101}{i=0+1}{%
  The pic \i
  \includegraphics[height=.45\textheight]{pic\zeropad{1234}{\i}}%
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to pad the numbers so that they are always four digits:

[image]

---

### Code: Test `\PadDigits` Macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand*{\PadDigits}[1]{%
    % #1 = number to pad
    \ifnum#1<10 
        000#1%
    \else
        \ifnum#1<100
            00#1%
        \else
        \ifnum#1<1000
            0#1%
        \else
            #1%
    \fi\fi\fi
}%
\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {0,9,99,999,1000} {%
    \par\noindent
    Padding \x = "\PadDigits{\x}"
}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: Use with `\includegraphics`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\PadDigits}[1]{%
    % #1 = number to pad
    \ifnum#1<10 
        000#1%
    \else
        \ifnum#1<100
            00#1%
        \else
        \ifnum#1<1000
            0#1%
        \else
            #1%
    \fi\fi\fi
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[controls]{6}
\multiframe{101}{i=0+1}{%
  The pic \i
  \includegraphics[height=.45\textheight]{pic\PadDigits{\i}}%
 }
\end{animateinline}
```

Comment: Just did a test with the animate package and it's work well, do you want that I post the MWE as an answer?

Comment: @aberration: Done. Note the addition of the trailing `%` -- just in case there was any shifting in the animation as you may have spurious spaces without those chars.

Answer (score 1):

Prepend the zeros as you go based on a condition:

```
\multiframe{101}{i=1+1}{%
  \includegraphics[height=50pt]{pic0\ifnum\number\i<100 0\fi\ifnum\number\i<10 0\fi\i}%
}
```

The first condition

```
\ifnum\number\i<100 0\fi
```

inserts a `0` if `\i` is less than 100. The second condition

```
\ifnum\number\i<10 0\fi
```

inserts a `0` if `\i` is less than 10. This establishes the correct formatting for your external files.