# Automatically construct image file name

Tags: graphics, automation, strings

I have a lot of images numbered like so:

```
image_0001.png
image_0002.png
image_0003.png
...
```

I would like to set up a Latex command to include a specific numbered image, for example:

```
\myimageinclude{3}
```

...would include `image_0003.png'.

In a Latex/C hybrid language this might look something like this:

```
\newcommand{\myimageinclude}[1]{%
   \includegraphics{sprintf('image_%04d.png', #1)]}}
```

But I am unsure of the string formation syntax. Is this possible in Latex?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86637/15925 for padding the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a command to convert your numbers to four-digits numbers adding leading zeroes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\fourdigits#1{%
  \ifnum#1<1000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1<100 0\fi
  \ifnum#1<10 0\fi
  \number#1}
\newcommand\myinclude[2][]{%
  \includegraphics[#1]{image_\fourdigits{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\myinclude[width=3cm]{18}

\end{document}
```

By the way, I'd rather noy use underscores in the names of the images files; perhaps a hyphen would be safer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, when number is less than 10:

```
\newcommand{\myimageinclude}[1]{%
\includegraphics{{image_000#1.png}}}
```

Do you need larger numbers?

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you have files 'image_1' and 'image_2' with suitable extensions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myimageinclude[1]{\includegraphics{image_#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\myimageinclude{1}
\myimageinclude{2}
\end{document}
```

You can insert zeros before the image number as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myimageinclude[1]{%
\ifnum #1 < 10
  \def\zs{000}
\else
  \ifnum #1 < 100
    \def\zs{00}
  \else
     \def\zs{0}
  \fi
\fi
\includegraphics{image_\zs#1}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\myimageinclude{1}
\myimageinclude{20}
\end{document}
```